# Custom iOS keyboard - Custom font output

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create a custom keyboard using the app keyboard extension. I am happy with the layout but the output is depended on the UITextField's font.

Is there a way to force a different font (use special characters?) while using the keyboard ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Text field (or any other view that draws text) uses 2 informations on how to show some text. One is the sequence of characters called `String` and the other one is how the string should be represented. The second one is then split it things like fonts, colors, line height, line breaking and wrapping...

So the keyboard alone is not enough to for instance present a certain part of word using different fonts. You need at least a bit of access to the item that represents the text. So if you have no access to your text field then the answer is; No, you can not fore a different font when using different keyboard.

If you do have the access then the answer should lie in `NSAttributedString`. It is a string you can assign to most items under `attributedText`. This class wraps your raw string and can add many properties to parts of text you want to change. That includes using a different font.

Another approach would be using HTML tags. Again you will need to process this using for instance `NSAttributedString` or display it with another element like web view.

I would try it with using `NSAttributedString`. Hook up to delegate and implement `textField(: shouldChangeCharactersIn: replacementString:`. The implementation itself may still not be easy though.